# System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=2.2.0.0,

Tags: c#, .net-core, aws-lambda, entity-framework-core, visual-studio-2019

I created a .net core 2.2 project using the AWS Lambda function template. Added a MySQL EntityFramework nuget package. My project targets .NET Core 2.2. I have code which uses DbContext and EF stuff. When I run the app using their lambda test tool, I get this error: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=2.2.0.0, .....

Using Process Monitor, I can see the app is trying to load Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll from ...\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll which doesn't exist.

My question is why aren't any of the supporting assemblies in that folder? The only assembly (.dll file) in the folder is my app's.

Answer (score 1):

Following step help you to solve this problem:

1. Delete all `bin` and `obj` folders.
2. Clean Solution. [Build>Clean Solution].
3. Rebuild Solution

Answer (score 1):

Try to use some type of `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` namespace explicitly somewhere in your code. For example:

```
var _ = new Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptionsBuilder();
```

It sould force the build to copy the assembly to result directory.

Comment: I think that is my answer. Now I have an error on system.threading.task.extensions as described at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60194368/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-threading-tasks-extensions-version-4-2

Answer (score 0):

I have some ideas.
Firstly check, if the folder that you want to refer allows the Visual to have access.

If it do not work, try reinstaling packages through nugget (If I remember correctly I had this same error.). If it shows that its not installed in nugget manager, just install it, even a few times.

Here is the anwser for your question at the end:
[Where does NuGet put the dll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7018913/where-does-nuget-put-the-dll)

Comment: If VS doesn't have access to the folder, it wouldn't be putting any files in there. VS creates that folder. The packages are installed and the solution compiles.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, in my case removing the line from the .csproj file helped

```
<PublishReadyToRun>true</PublishReadyToRun>
```