# Multiperson team with multiple NuGet package sources and prebuild events fail

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nuget, nuget-package

I am currently working on a multiperson team and we have recently starting using NuGet.  Our projects are setup with a prebuild event so that each person keeps in sycn and we keep the packages out of source control.  This has worked well.

```
"$(SolutionDir)nuget" install "$(ProjectDir)packages.config" -o "$(SolutionDir)Packages"
```

We recently have setup an internal network drive for hosting company specific packages.  I added the network location to my package sources.  I am able to create the package and reference it fine.

When a team member adds the internal package source and does a build they get the "this command exited with code1." error and the package contents from the local packages are not copied over.

I saw this question, [Multiperson team using NuGet and Source Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7015149/multiperson-team-using-nuget-and-source-control), and tried to add the -source option but the error still exists.

Looking at packages.config, it doesn't seem to specify which package source a package came from.

What do we need to do in order to effectively use multiple package sources in a mutliperson environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try upgrading to using the new [workflow](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages). It doesn't use prebuild events but it give the same net effect. It will also show the actual error message (if there's any). You can also specify sources to use for restore in the targets file used by this technique.